# How to install public certificate .cer in Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, azure-functions, azure-appservice

I'm trying to make a call to a wcf service from an Azure function hosted in Azure. The wcf service requires a certificate.

I'm able to call to wcf service when I do debug in local machine (I import successfully the cert) but in Azure I got the error "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'."

I believe this is due to missing certificate in Azure side.

I try to upload the .cer to Public Key Certificates (.cer) but still doesn't work. My Function app still returns the same error "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'."

Please let me know how to make my request accept in wcf service?
It would be nice if we have solution in Azure Portal rather than doing PowerShell.

Note: I use the same certification and source code when I do debug in local machine and when I publish to Azure Function.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59290464/how-to-fix-the-http-request-was-forbidden-with-client-authentication-scheme-an)

Comment: You can refer to ["The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'."](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/caa0584e-d460-4bf4-98a8-d20f8232adc1/quotthe-http-request-was-forbidden-with-client-authentication-scheme-anonymousquot?forum=wcf) and [HTTP and HTTPS / The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/517121/http-and-https-the-http-request-was-forbidden-with.html)

Comment: Hi DeepDave, I believe this is due to missing certificate in Azure side so I want to ask for importing certificate in Azure Function. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the tutorial.https://devkimchi.com/2020/10/14/lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-on-azure-functions/  && https://jan-v.nl/post/loading-certificates-with-azure-functions/  && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65676319/how-to-call-wcf-in-azure-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your time.

The issue has been resolved in WCF side. The WCF guy adds the Azure Function IP address to the white list and it works. It's nothing to do with Azure Function.

Looks like the same issue with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32994974/4489400).